# perl cpan installation error

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

I tried installing cpan for `strawberry perl` with following `cpan App::cpanminus`.
But following is the error I got. Could you please guide how can I resolve this issue?

```
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin>cpan app::cpanminus
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.204)
Database was generated on Thu, 02 Apr 2015 07:11:45 GMT

Warning: Cannot install app::cpanminus, don't know what it is.
Try the command

i /app::cpanminus/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9726)

C:\Strawberry\perl\bin>i /app::cpanminus/
'i' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: `cpan App::cpanminus`

Answer (score 1):

To install it without using `cpan`, the basic bootstrap procedure is:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

For more information see the installation section at [App::cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7027/lib/App/cpanminus.pm)